# bad_alloc error when implementing vector resize function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, resize, bad-alloc

I am trying to implement `Vector::resize()` function in C++. I think I handled each situation but still get a `bad_alloc` error. Three cases in this resize implementation:

1. when `new_size` is smaller than the `old_size` (in my code, `size`);
2. when `new_size` is bigger than `size` but smaller than capacity;
3. when `new_size` is bigger than capacity

Here is my code:

```
void Vector::resize(int new_size)
{
    //if the new_size is smaller, make the size smaller, don't need to worry about memory
    //the content is reduced to its first n elements
    //remove those beyond and destroy them
    
    if(new_size < size){
        
        for(int i = size-1; i > new_size; i--){
            erase(i);
        }
        size = new_size;
    }
    
    //if the new_size is bigger
    //case 1: new_size is smaller than capacity
    //inserting at the end of as many elements as needed
    if(new_size > size && new_size < capacity){
        
        for(int i=size; i < new_size; i++){
            insert(i, 0.0);
        }
        size = new_size;
        
    }
    
    //case 2: new_size is greater than capacity
    //increase the capacity of the container
    
    //increase the capacity to new_size
    double *tmp_data = new double(new_size);
    
    //transfer data to tmp_data
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tmp_data[i] = data[i];
    }
    
    data = tmp_data;
    delete [] data;
    
    size = new_size;
    capacity = new_size; 
}
```

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` is thrown when `new` cannot allocate the requested memory.

Comment: Please fix signed/unsigned warnings (some of these are errors)

Comment: Could you explain to us why you are doing that (reinventing the wheel) ? What's wrong with `std::vector` ? Or is that homework ?

Comment: @kebs yes, I'm required to implement it instead of using the library. And I happen to choose Vector as my class name but I didn't include the library in my program.

Answer (score 5):

There are several things wrong with this code. The one that jumps out first is:

```
//increase the capacity to new_size
double *tmp_data = new double(new_size);
```

You intend to allocate an array, but are actually allocating a single `double`. You meant:

```
double *tmp_data = new double[new_size];
```

Although, once you fix that...

```
data = tmp_data;
delete [] data;
```

You want to do those in the opposite order, otherwise you're leaving yourself with a deleted member.

And once you fix *that*, you want to `return` from your cases early. You have three cases (not two, as your comments would suggest), and you only want to reallocate in the case that you actually need to (i.e. case #3). As-is, you're reallocating in all your cases.

Comment: The first and second point is correct, and I fixed it. It now could handle both case 1(new_size < size) and case 3(new_size > capacity). However, case 2(new_size> size && new_size < capacity) is not correct. It changed the capacity to new_size, which I think is related to your last point, which i don't quite understand.

Comment: I see my problem now. Forgot the if condition in my case 3. Sorry for asking careless.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Barry, you had a few bugs in the original.

Here is your code with a few suggestions:

```
void Vector::resize(int new_size)
{
    if(new_size <= size) {     // use "<=" here

        // if you are dealing with doubles, what is there to erase?
        // (I would remove that loop)
        for(int i = size-1; i > new_size; i--){
            erase(i);
        }
        size = new_size;

        return;   // you're done here, you can return
    }
    
    if(new_size <= capacity) {    // again "<=", if you return, then no need for anything more

        // "insert()" sounds confusing, you're doing a set() here
        for(int i=size; i < new_size; i++){
            insert(i, 0.0);
        }
        size = new_size;

        return;   // again, you can now return, you're done
    }
    
    double *tmp_data = new double(new_size);
    
    // you could use std::copy() here
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tmp_data[i] = data[i];
    }
    
    // as indicated by Barry, you could inverse these
    delete [] data;
    data = tmp_data;
    
    size = new_size;
    capacity = new_size; 
}
```

I removed all your comments and put my own for you perusal.

Another way to handle 3 cases like these is to use the else keyword like so:

```
if(new_size <= size) {
    ...
} else if(new_size <= capacity) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

And to make it clear, you could have three sub-functions you call from each `...` cases. That way you see the main logic of your `resize()` function.